# Reading Data in your PHP app from HTTPS website

Tags: php, curl

I want to read data from https://partner.bosch.de/ew/ro/ , as I have to search products from here. My client is having login details to login, he enters some id's in a form and on submit it gives get data from here in an excel sheet. Afterwards using that excel sheet a data entry operator has to enter data on own store.

What I want is to read data using CURL or REST API from my own website. Above mentioned website is not offering any api.

Comment: Post your code and we will be able to tell you what might be wrong.

Comment: I am sasking for a way to implement this solution.

Comment: Try curl and set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this.

Comment: I will get back to you in case of any problem.

Comment: Actually I can't get welcome screen in my example.com

Comment: What I want is:

Comment: 1. Stay on own site, Login to bosch
2. Read Data from bosch in excel and use that to update database.

Comment: 1. Firstly you want your cookies to persist for subsequent requests via curl.
2. Secondly you have to download the excel file using some simulation. 
PS: Not sure in php but there is mechanize module in perl which simulates as a user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CURL you will found more details here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('text/xml; charset=utf-8'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score -1):

See this is the source code of above given link, they have used a frame basically, know when I go on src of that frame its not giving me exact idea, how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <META http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <META http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <META http-equiv="Expires" content="now">
<title></title>
</head>

<frameset frameborder="0" border="0" rows="0,*">
    <frame src="dummy.html" frameborder="NO">
    <frame
    src="https://app6.bosch.de/cgi-bin/WebObjects.dll/V5Prod_WES_ND.woa?pkbereich=986&language=ro"
    frameborder="NO" name="topFrame">
    <noframes>
    <body>
    </body>
    </noframes>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: and then how u use data in iframe ?

Comment: I have fixed it dear